# Android Studio not recognizing mp3 files

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I try to play  mp3 file in my flutter project, but when i import the files into the raw directory they look like this:

```
 Future<void> repeatNotification() async {
    var androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'CHANNEL_ID 3',
      'CHANNEL_NAME 3',
      "CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION 3",
      playSound: true,
      enableLights: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      // sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),
      styleInformation: DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
    );
    var iosChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidChannelSpecifics, iOS: iosChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      0,
      'Repeating Test Title',
      'Repeating Test Body',
      RepeatInterval.everyMinute,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Test Payload',
    );
  }
```

[image]

What I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

**if you want play sound in flutter project:**

1. go to Your flutter root project
2. create "assets" folder
3. create custom directory like sound
4. put your sound file there
5. open "pubspec.yaml" file
6. find "assets" and remove "#" character(in addition, you must remove
   a space before assets)
7. give your created directory address like this: assets/sounds/
8. add audioPlayer and path_provider to your project

sample code:

```
//load
final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/sounds/demo.mp3');
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
File tempFile = File('${tempDir.path}/demo.mp3');
await tempFile.writeAsBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List(), flush: true);
mp3Uri = tempFile.uri.toString();


//play
if(mp3Uri != null)
    audioPlayer.play(mp3Uri, isLocal: true);
```

Comment: i did that but Not working bro . i have the same problem .@amir hossein

Comment: check this is more clear : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67902929/default-local-notification-sound-doesnt-work-flutter?noredirect=1#comment120020285_67902929 . @amir hossein